# How to set default file in <Input type="file">?

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is for select-file by user. But I want to render the default selected file on page load.

```
<input type="file" id="file-upload" accept="application/pdf" value="Upload/<?php echo $_GET['id9']; ?>" />
```

Comment: Like this: `value="\user\bhatti\allpasswords.dat"`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to set a default value for a input file :(

More info here:
[How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Loosely interpreting the answer seems to contain the essential parts of the linked answer: "not possible" ...